# Form select box {!!Form::select()!!} Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel Collective Form builder in my view and i'm populating this select box from a table in my DB like this

I am having an issue with my values not matching up and my dropdown is also giving me the values as an array...

Here's what I have in my **PostsController**:-

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $categories = Category::all()->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();

    return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($categories);
}
```

and here's my view **edit.blade.php**:-

```
{{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category :')}}
{!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

So I need little help?

Here's the value issue I was talking about:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew4j2.jpg)

Here's the array issue I was talking about:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM5kx.jpg)

Comment: laravel version and collective version please

Comment: Laravel version 5.8.9 and Im not sure what collective version?...

Answer (score 3):

no need to use `toArray()` pluck method automatically create an array.
try this

```
$categories = Category::pluck('title', 'id');
```

Comment: I took out the "all" and "toArray" but that too didn't work? It didn't break it, but I'm still having the same issues...

Comment: show me what is the result if you return dd ($categories)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code seems like not proper.

```
    $categories = Category::all()->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
```

should be

```
    $categories = Category::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly update you controller function. I think that will help:-

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $categories = Category::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();

    return view('posts.edit', [
            'post' => $post,
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
}
```

Try this code and let me know need help.

Comment: I tied using your solutions above, but that didn't work for me and nothing changed...

Comment: can you provide me output of `$categories` variable in your view file?

Comment: I'm very new at Laravel, so I'm not sure when you say "output of $categories variable in your view file" what you actually need or how to get it to you...

Comment: In your view file add this line `{{dd($categories)}}`. And share output.

Comment: I just got it to work, so thx... I had to change the name in the "function edit" from $categories to $cats..and now it works. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ImaginRPower Great.. you can upvote my answer as appreciation.